# Is the navigation graph obsolete when I use Jetpack Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Before I use a navigation graph in my Android Studio project, just like the [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) says.

I use an xml file located in `res\navigation` folder to include all my different destinations.

At present, I'm learning Jetpack Compose Navigation by the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation).

Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab) mentioned in the above article.

It seems that Jetpack Compose Navigation use Code A and other codes to navigate, and I can't find any XML file in `res\navigation` folder.

1: Is the navigation graph obsoleted when I use Jetpack Compose Navigation ?

2: Don't I need to use the navigation graph located in `res\navigation` folder again when I use Jetpack Compose Navigation?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun RallyNavHost(navController: NavHostController, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Overview.name,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(Overview.name) {
            OverviewBody(
                onClickSeeAllAccounts = { navController.navigate(Accounts.name) },
                onClickSeeAllBills = { navController.navigate(Bills.name) },
                onAccountClick = { name ->
                    navigateToSingleAccount(navController, name)
                },
            )
        }
        composable(Accounts.name) {
            AccountsBody(accounts = UserData.accounts) { name ->
                navigateToSingleAccount(navController = navController, accountName = name)
            }
        }
        composable(Bills.name) {
            BillsBody(bills = UserData.bills)
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.- it's not strictly a deprecation if you still using navigation with the view system, but if you are planning a migration to use jetpack compose + navigation, the paradigm changes, since now you need to use a NavHostController to reach the correct compose destination.

Comment: 2.- No, you use a NavHost + NavHostController to reach the correct composable function.

Comment: May be this code help you https://github.com/orbitalsonic/Android-Jetpack-Compose-Navigation-Kotlin-Example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Navigation has always had three ways of building a `NavGraph` object:

1. Manually, by using the `NavGraph` constructor itself. While this serves as the basis for all other methods listed here, you aren't meant to use these APIs directly.
2. Building the graph via [Navigation XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-create-destinations). This is a way of building a graph at compile time using the Navigator Editor tooling and the [Safe Args plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args). This method only supports Navigation with Fragments.
3. Using the [Navigation Kotlin DSL](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-kotlin-dsl). This provides a type-safe way of building a navigation graph programmatically, at runtime by using a [Kotlin DSL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html). This method supports both Navigation with Fragments and Navigation Compose.

As Compose is a way of programmatically building your UI, Navigation only supports the programmatic version of building the graph - via that Kotlin DSL that is exactly what that trailing lambda of `NavHost` provides you: it is that same `NavGraphBuilder` scope that allows you to call `navigation(...) {}` to build a [nested graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs) or `composable` to add a new destination to your graph.

All of the concepts are the same because the underlying `NavGraph` you construct ends up being the exact same set of objects at runtime, no matter how you actually build the graph.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that the Code A use the third way (Using the Navigation Kotlin DSL.) to build a NavGraph object ?

Comment: Correct, Code A is using the Kotlin DSL (that's the only supported way to build a navigation graph for Navigation Compose, as per my answer).